# Royal Enfield classic 350 bs6 very low rpm and engine shutting down

Tags: troubleshooting, rpm, royal-enfield, stopping, accelerator

My royal Enfield classic 350 bs6 reddit grey vehicle has some engine shutdown problem.

Sometimes when I start the vehicle, it was not starting automatically, I need to give some accelerator to get it start. Also the engine running very slow rpm and shutting down automatically.

Even when I was driving, during the gear change, we need to press clutch, during clutch engine slowing down and shutting down

What could be the cause, how can we rectify, please help

Comment: It shouldn't have changed by itself, but perhaps you only need to adjust the idle speed screw. This should open up the throttle valve more on idle, increasing idle speed and making it start better. It should be located somewhere below the throttle body on the rear of the cylinder head.

Comment: There is no valve or screw in bs6